# How to representation math text using latex or overleaf code?

Tags: overleaf

I have written math-text with following latex code:

```
    \begin{align}
    \emph{HPEI} = \{ \mathcal{H}_{1},\mathcal{H}_{2}, ...\mathcal{H}_{i},...  \mathcal{H}_{m}\}.
    \end{align}
```

but the first element of the set looks different as:

[image]

How may I represent it as other elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get a good deal of errors with the code. The problem is that `\emph` is a *text* command and cannot be used in math. Besides it is *not* for typesetting text in italics: its meaning is *emphasis*.

Use `\mathit` instead. Besides, don't use `align` for single equations. A couple of commas were missing and `\dots` is better than `...`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathit{HPEI} =
  \{
  \mathcal{H}_{1},\mathcal{H}_{2},\dots,\mathcal{H}_{i},\dots,\mathcal{H}_{m}
  \}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I agree with everything you say, but I find myself wondering _why_ we shouldn’t use `align` for single equations. If I replace `equation` with `align` do I not get the same output? There’s even a case for using `align` and `&=` for a single equation, so that you can cut/paste equations and things keep working.